# Cucmber.js step is getting passed even though expect should have failed

Tags: protractor, cucumberjs, chai-as-promised

My Cucumber step is getting passed even though expect statement is failing. It seems steps is running before expect statement is completed.

Please let me know how can I instruct the cucumber step to fail if expect is getting failed.

[Folder Structure]  Following is my Feature file

```
    #features/test.feature


 Feature: Running Cucumber with Protractor
    As a user of Protractor
    I should be able to use Cucumber
    In order to run my E2E tests

    Scenario: Protractor and Cucumber Test
        Given I go to "https://angularjs.org/"
        When I add "Be Awesome" in the task field
        And I click the add button
        Then I should see my new task in the list
```

Following is Step Definition

```
var chai = require('chai'),
    expect = chai.expect,
    chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);

chai.should();

var {defineSupportCode} = require('cucumber');
let scenarioTimeout = 200 * 1000;

defineSupportCode(({setDefaultTimeout}) => {
    setDefaultTimeout(scenarioTimeout);
});

defineSupportCode(function({Given, When, Then}) {  
  Given(/^I go to "([^"]*)"$/, function(site) {
    return browser.get(site);
  });

  When(/^I add "([^"]*)" in the task field$/, function(task) {
    return element(by.model('todoList.todoText')).sendKeys(task);
  });

  When(/^I click the add button$/, function() {
  var el = element(by.css('[value="add"]'));
   return el.click();
  });

  Then(/^I should see my new task in the list$/, function() {
    var todoList = element.all(by.repeater('todo in todoList.todos'));
    return expect(todoList.get(2).getText()).to.eventually.equal('Not Awesome');


  });
});
```

All works well If I write Then step as below :

Solution 1:

```
    element.all(by.repeater('todo in todoList.todos')).then(function(items){
expect(items[2].getText()).to.eventually.equal('Not Awesome').and.notify(callback);
});
```

Solution2:

```
return element.all(by.repeater('todo in todoList.todos')).then(function(items){
return expect(items[2].getText()).to.eventually.equal('Not Awesome');
});
```

I really want to understand why it did not work if I have written Then step in the below way:

```
Then(/^I should see my new task in the list$/, function() {
```

```
var todoList = element.all(by.repeater('todo in todoList.todos'));
    return expect(todoList.get(2).getText()).to.eventually.equal('Not Awesome');
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to solve the issue.

Chai-as-promised version was 6.0 and it peer dependency is Chai version >=2.1.2 and < 4.
I was having the chai version > 4 so I downgraded to version 2.1.2 and it all worked smoothly.